# Connection refused from localhost to localhost

Tags: networking, linux-networking, netcat

I started a tcp listener using nc -l 127.0.0.1 900 and then attempted to connect to it using nc 127.0.0.1 900 when I got the *connection refused* error. The same happens when connecting using telnet. ufw is disabled. I don't understand how this could happen. Please throw some light onto this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [Simple client / server with nc not working](https://serverfault.com/q/960798/126632)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some versions of `nc` has strange behavior, related with specifying of listening port and listening address. Try to run `nc` with `-v` (`verbosity`) option:

```
~# nc -v -l 127.0.0.1 900
listening on 0.0.0.0:36915 ...
^C

~# nc -v -l 127.0.0.1 -p 900
listening on 0.0.0.0:900 ...
^C
```

Other way to troubleshoot similar issues is checking of the listened sockets:

```
~# ss -tlnp | grep nc
LISTEN     0      1            *:43395   *:*      (("nc",pid=2210,fd=3))
```

Comment: You're welcome. So, try use the `nc -l <local-ip> -p <local-port>` command to . Also accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
`~# ss -tlnp | grep nc`
gave the following output:
`~LISTEN   0         1                   0.0.0.0:39373            0.0.0.0:*   users (("nc",pid=2708,fd=3))`

Is the wildcard IP something to be worried about?
Why is netcat behaving like this?
Using plain old C socket server solved the issue.
Also, `ip link` shows the state of `lo` as `UNKNOWN`, does this relate in anyway to the strange behaviour?

Comment: When you bind nc to `127.0.0.1`, connections can be established only from same host. In case of binding to `0.0.0.0` connection will be accepted from everywhere, so you need use the firewall to limit the access. Your issue with `nc` doesn't related with state `UNKNOWN` of `lo` interface in the `ip link` output. I don't know why `nc` behaves like this.